# Better ways to test bytes32 type using truffle testing framework

Tags: truffle-test, assert, hex

small quick question, when I store a `bytes32` and retrieve it from truffle console, why is it showing in 64 bits?

Ex: `0x74657374737472696e6700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

because this is kinda annoying when it comes to using truffle testing framework.

`assert.equal(data[1].toUpperCase(), "0x74657374737472696e6700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000".toUpperCase(), "name doesn't match");`

When testing `bytes32` data, I have to match an exact 64 bits hex value in order to pass. So for `assert.equal`'s second parameter where I would enter in my predicted value, I have to manually convert a string to hex using mostly from this [site](https://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter), and in fact most of the string to hex sites do not show in full 64 bits. They would show it as: `74657374737472696e67`.

It is annoying that I have to count the zeros and append them to match 64 bits. 
Are there any handy ways to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values you're showing are 32 bytes long (256 bits), not 64 bits.

They're that length because the type is `bytes32`. The number `1` is different from `10`, and the same holds in hexadecimal. You can't just drop the trailing zeros without changing the value.

Assuming you're always working with strings, you could use `web3.toAscii`... e.g. `assert.toEqual(web3.toAscii(data[1]), "teststring");`.

(FYI, I think in web3.js 1.0 beta, the function is `web3.utils.toAscii`.)

Comment: It turns out that it's giving an error: `expected 'teststring\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\.............`. I guess I need to find a way to get rid of `\u0000`s

Comment: Try `web3.toAscii(data[1]).replace(/\0/g, '')` instead.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Do you think truffle should take this into consideration for testing? People must be testing a lot with `bytes32` values.

Comment: why is it showing as null(`\u0000`) by the way?

Comment: In Unicode, `\uXXXX` indicates a unicode character with the value XXXX (in this case, 0).

Comment: (See http://json.org/.)

Comment: I don't use Truffle, so I don't know if they have some other built in string<-->bytes32 comparison. If not, I suppose it would be useful, though `web3.toAscii` is a fine solution.

Comment: oh so that indicates trailing zeros are showing as `\u0000`?